# Virtualmin domain name registration in PHP

Tags: php

In a PHP web page I need to run this following command to create a new domain:

```
virtualmin create-domain --domain DOMAIN --pass PASS --plan 'Standard Package' --limits-from-plan --features-from-plan
```

This is usually executed in a shell but I don’t know how to do it from a web page and also I need to take the `DOMAIN` and `PASS` strings from a web form. Can anyone help with the PHP code? My skills are basic and I have already tried a few things that just don’t work.

Comment: what things you have tried? Why not to bring it here - what have you tried and what exact result, including error messages, you get?

Answer (score 0):

How about [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) ?:

```
shell_exec("virtualmin create-domain --domain DOMAIN (...)");
```

or the [`backtick operator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php):

```
`virtualmin create-domain --domain DOMAIN (...)`
```

---

You can access parameters submitted via a HTML form with the `$_POST` array. But make sure to validate the user input. I suggest to read a [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php) about this.

Comment: i have tried this and will not work, i'm using php else where on my server but this one command will not work

<html>
<body>

<?

shell_exec("mkdir hello");

?>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @David Maitland: Is safe mode enabled? If so, the exec commands might not work. You can search on SO for this issue. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+execute+shell+command

Comment: no its turned off just checked in the php.ini files and in virtualmin PHP configuration

Answer (score -1):

You have to run this command as root or using sudo. I'm currently looking into the same thing, but there doesn't seem to be a 100% safe and secure way of running it using root/sudo.

However, if you would like, you can call a script in php as sudo and change password request off. You can pass the variables into it

```
 exec("sudo /your/script.sh $Domain $Pass");
```

Your bash script would look like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 domain=$1
 pass=$2
 virtualmin create-domain --domain $domain --pass $pass --plan 'Standard Package' --limits-from-plan --features-from-plan
```

You should allow executing your script without password prompt. Run `sudo visudo` in console and add the following string to the end:

```
 nobody ALL = NOPASSWD: /your/script
```

You must set up file mode properly to ensure that no one can modify this script and put dangerous contents into it (in root console):

```
 chown root:root /your/script
 chmod 755 /your/script
```

Info sourced from: [How to run from PHP a bash script under root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915241/how-to-run-from-php-a-bash-script-under-root-user) 
and [Pass PHP variables to a Bash script and then launch it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903506/pass-php-variables-to-a-bash-script-and-then-launch-it)

Comment: Dangerous like hell. PHP + root = tick, tick, KABOOM!

Comment: "but there doesn't seem to be a 100% safe and secure way of running it using root/sudo." - I did mention that mate...