# How to run from PHP a bash script under root user

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, unix

How to run from PHP a bash script under **root user** (with all permissions) and not **nobody** user - php default user?

thats my output after sudo visudo:

```
Defaults        env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
Defaults        env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
Defaults        env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Defaults        env_keep += "TZ"
Defaults        env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
Defaults        env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
Defaults        env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

#User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL


# Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Samples
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Comment: This sounds dangerous, so raises the obvious question: why do you need to do this?  Perhaps this is a better overall solution.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use sudo:

```
exec("sudo /your/script");
```

You should allow executing your script without password prompt. Run `sudo visudo` in console and add the following string to the end:

```
nobody ALL = NOPASSWD: /your/script
```

You must set up file mode properly to ensure that no one can modify this script and put dangerous contents into it (in root console):

```
chown root:root /your/script
chmod 755 /your/script
```

Comment: Where exactly i should add it? I publish my output after `sudo visudo` in the question

Comment: Just put new line to the end of file.

Comment: @Riateche I did it all! cant run it... i am calling to xcodebuilde(Unix program) -nothing happens, in terminal works file.

Comment: Check return value of `exec` function. Pass `$output` and `$return_var` parameters and check their values too. They could contain some useful information.

Comment: checked it. `output`=Array and `return_var`=69.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a program which is set-uid root. This causes the program to always run as root. This doesn't work with shell scripts, so you have to use a [program which calls your script](http://web.archive.org/web/20120305024140/http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html).

Comment: The link seems broken.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux you normally do this using `sudo`. Try to be as specific as possible, so not to give the script too many permissions.

For examples on how to use `sudo`: http://aplawrence.com/Basics/sudo.html

Comment: The problem is that when i run it on terminal its works good, but when i run that bash script from php it isn't executed (other simple bash with `cp`,`mv` commands working), i think its 90% permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a specific rule to allow this script to be called by `nobody` user, using `sudo`.

Comment: See Riateche's answer - you need to add the line `nobody ALL = NOPASSWD: /your/script` to the "visudo" file (sudoers configuration file). Of course, substitute `/your/script` by the path to your script.

Comment: How can i edit this file? i used `sudo visudo` but it's shows only the output.

Comment: Strange. `sudo visudo` should open it in a file editor: http://www.google.com.br/search?q=visudo

Comment: You can change the editor visudo uses by typing `EDITOR=nano` (for example)... in "nano", use CTRL+O, CTRL+X to save the file...

Comment: I cant do nothing with it, i open the file - Cant save it, it wont close, its duplicates himself....

Comment: This is really bad, and it shouldn't happen using `visudo`... see http://serverfault.com/questions/320109/how-to-change-back-etc-sudoers-file-right-to-0440

Comment: It seems you are not used to edit files in the CLI environment (i.e., using text editors like "Vim" or "Nano")... at least do you know which editor are you using?

Comment: Ok, i played with it... **to write: you press 'I' . to save changes its ESC and ':w'**

Answer (score -1):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell (as user: apache/www-data or root if needed). Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('/full/path/to/script.sh');
```