# Execute / run excutable under root using php from a webpage

Tags: php, exec

I want to run a executable file on my server when a user clicks a button on webpage.
I am able to run the executable using exec command but the program runs under 'nobody' even if I followed the instructions in post : [How to run from PHP a bash script under root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915241/how-to-run-from-php-a-bash-script-under-root-user) answer by : Riateche

But still the execuable file runs under 'nobody'

My executable program is kept in directory

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/project
```

My php code

```
<?
$variable = 10;
$site_dir = 'project';
echo "<img src ='".exec('/opt/lampp/htdocs/' . $site_dir .'/myProgram '.' '.$_GET['value1'] .' '. $variable )."'>";
?>
```

Comment: You should probably also share your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `sudo` keyword before your command:

```
echo "<img src ='".exec('/opt/lampp/htdocs/' . $site_dir .'/myProgram '.' '.$_GET['value1'] .' '. $variable )."'>";
```

Should be:

```
echo "<img src ='".exec('sudo /opt/lampp/htdocs/' . $site_dir .'/myProgram '.' '.$_GET['value1'] .' '. $variable )."'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add a rule to sudo users/rules file to allow your command to run without entering your or root password. This link might tell you how to do that. here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo