# run bash script as root from php page

Tags: bash, sudo, chmod, chown

I have a php page.

It calls a validation bash script that checks variables passed from the php page.

I then call another bash script that I need to execute under root user.  I have followed the guide here [How to run from PHP a bash script under root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915241/how-to-run-from-php-a-bash-script-under-root-user) and still can not get script to execute as root.

I have the following:

php page

```
$bashFile = shell_exec('./Validation.sh "'.$coinName.'" "'.$coinNameAbreviation.'" "'.$blockReward.'" "'.$blockSpacing.'" "'.$targetTimespan.'" "'.$totalCoins.'" "'.$firstBitAddy.'" "'.$seedNode.'" "'.$seedName.'" "'.$headline.'" ');
echo "<pre>$bashFile</pre>";
```

the validation file:

```
sudo nohup /bin/bash /usr/sbin/CoinCreationBashFile "$coinName" "$coinNameAbreviation" "$blockReward" "$blockSpacing" "$targetTimespan" "$totalCoins" "$firstAddyBit" "$seedNode" "$nameSeedNode" "$headline" "$blocksPerDay" "$startingDifficulty" >> /tmp/BASH2log.txt 2>&1 &
```

I have added

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD /usr/sbin/CoinCreationBashFile
```

to the end of the sudo visudo

and did:

```
chown root:root /usr/sbin/CoinCreationBashFile
chmod 755 /usr/sbin/CoinCreationBashFile
```

was running it from usr/sbin from suggestion here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1848069 
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?? Many thanks
edit: I can run the CoinCreationBashFile script without the sudo command and it runs ok up to one point where it needs root priv... so i know the script working, and executing from the terminal the script runs perfectly as desired.  output in tmp/BASH2log.txt

```
sudo: no tty present and noaskpass program specified
```

Comment: maybe your www server uses different user account (not www-data)?

Comment: when i run top in the terminal on the server that is the user that is executing all the processes

Comment: can you clarify if you succesfully ran the script as www-data user without password?

Comment: yes script can be run when i typed sudo -u www-data /usr/sbin/CoinCreationBashFile var1 var2 var3

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. Did you try to su to www-data (sudo -u www-data bash) and then run a script (sudo /usr/sbin/CoinCreationBashFile var1 var2 var3)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the correct test for this and yes the script can run when logged in as www-data by typing su www-data, then running sudo script var1 var2 runs script fine no password prompts

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35114/discussion-between-peter-and-gawi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is similar to [sudo in php exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec) and they did not arrive at a conclusion.

<strike>In your case, since only one bash script needs to be executed in this fashion, considering [using setuid](http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html) instead:</strike>

```
$ su
[enter password]
chown root:root something.sh
chmod 4755 something.sh
exit
```

**Note**: Some Linux distributions disable setuid for shell scripts by default for security reasons.

**Update**: Apparently [no commonly used Linux distribution today allows setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts). Perl used to be the exception, but [suid-perl is now deprecated](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html#Deprecations).

The only way to execute your bash script using this method is to invoke it from a compiled binary. See [the example with the C code](http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html) on how to do this.

Comment: I was wondering if the linux disabled setuid... am on ubuntu 12.04 for the OS.  Have run chown root:root /usr/sbin/CoinCreationBashFile and chmod 4755 /usr/sbin/CoinCreationBashFile from the terminal.. was wondering if the link guide was saying to make seperate bash file to change the user.. but would have thought that done now I have run it as root from terminal

Comment: @Peter Updated my answer after some research.

Comment: solution i used was to get php page to write out variables to a txt file in empty directory.  At the start of my bash script that php page was calling it now searches for a .txt file in the empty directory, if no txt file then exit, if there is then extract variables and run cron job.  Many thanks for your help Niklas

Answer (score 2):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell, you can easily get a shell with root. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);

$strCmd = "/usr/sbin/CoinCreationBashFile ".$coinName." ".$coinNameAbreviation." ".$blockReward." ".$blockSpacing." ".$targetTimespan." ".$totalCoins." ".$firstAddyBit." ".$seedNode." ".$nameSeedNode." ".$headline." ".$blocksPerDay." ".$startingDifficulty." >> /tmp/BASH2log.txt 2>&1 &";
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd($strCmd);

//if there is any return from the script you can wait for the return
//or you can trigger like you have it now and get no return.
```

Comment: What are the security risks associated with this?

Comment: Since you require root permissions the project i built achieves that in one of 2 ways:

You allow apache the right to sudo python OR you pass root credentials to the object every time you need a shell with root setup.

Allowing sudo to python is a real concern, but so is passing root credentials in the script. Letting PHP anywhere near root is always tricky. Pick your poison. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in visudo entry. There is no R in the NOPASSWD. It should be:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD /usr/sbin/CoinCreationBashFile
```

Comment: good spot but unfortunately only a typo in the question on here.. in code it was PASSWD and still does not work :(