# PHP: Run Shell Script as root user

Tags: php, bash, shell

I'm trying to run a script as root user. here is my code

```
echo shell_exec("sudo bash.sh 2>&1");
```

It's giving error

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
www-data is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I've followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915241/how-to-run-from-php-a-bash-script-under-root-user?answertab=active#10915397)  methods as well but end up with `no permission` error

Comment: sudo is interactive, and you're running it from a script, that's why it fails, there is no way for the script to supply the password. Is it possible for you to run PHP with sudo, in which case the script would have root permissions anyway? eg `sudo php script.php`

Comment: actually it depends on how the system is configured. you can make sudo work without asking a password

Comment: post your entry in /etc/sudoers

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon yes youre right, just reading the man page now. You could use the -S option (I *think*) to pass in the password via stdin, so you could do this in a one-liner. Have a look at the manual: http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html

Comment: although the security implications of actually doing that are monstrous. please don't, atleast in a production environment.

Comment: @jammypeach that's wrong, you can pipe username and password to sudo with `proc_open()`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany which part is wrong? my first comment is but is the second wrong also? I didn't know you could use `proc_open()`, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues you might encounter:

- The user that is running the php process must have sudo rights (check with `visudoers` command)
- There is no environment set, so the `$PATH` variable does not include the path to the sudo command
- `sudo` might require a password. Either change the sudoers file, adding `NOPASSWORD`, which would be hugely unsafe. Or you have to use pipes (`proc_open`), and pass the password through the stdin pipe

I've managed to find a way to do so, but after some help from people on this site:

[load .profile with proc_open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843550/load-profile-with-proc-open)
[proc_open interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102952/proc-open-interaction)