# How to access root packages through php?

Tags: php, shell, root, permission-denied

**Issue:** Initially, Through command line as a root user,I accessed a package called **`pandoc (/root/.cabal/bin/pandoc)`** which was installed in root folder. When I try to access that package through php using **`shell_exec()`**,it fails.

**Question:** Is there any limitation for php **`shell_exec()`** not to access root packages for security purposes? If so,how to resolve it?

**I tried:** Gave write permission to root folder then I could access root packages through 
command line not as a root user. yet I couldn't to access it through php **`shell_exec()`**.

php code:

```
shell_exec("cd /home/quotequadsco/public_html/pandoc_jats ; sudo -u quotequadsco 
-S /root/.cabal/bin/pandoc ex.tex --filter /root/.cabal/bin/pandoc-citeproc
-t JATS.lua -o ex.xml");
```

and also tried,

```
shell_exec("cd /home/quotequadsco/public_html/pandoc_jats ;/root/.cabal/bin/pandoc 
ex.tex --filter /root/.cabal/bin/pandoc-citeproc -t JATS.lua -o ex.xml");
```

**Expectation:** I need to execute pandoc root package through **`shell_exec()`**  in php.

Comment: How are you running this script? What user is Apache running under?

Comment: php file in public_html folder running under quotequadsco user

Comment: Then its not going to work you sure its quotequadsco and not www-data?, you will need to setup apache to run as root, which is unsafe but possible

Comment: Then what would be the safest option to resolve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915241/how-to-run-from-php-a-bash-script-under-root-user

Comment: I tried the option you suggested in the link but none of them worked

Comment: I think I have to edit in the sudoers file. Its centOS linux. Can you tell me what are the lines should be added in the sudoers file to run shell_exec as root for specific command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following line in the /etc/sudoer file

```
#Defaults requiretty   //commented this line
usergroup ALL=(ALL)  ALL
```

PHP code,

```
shell_exec("cd /home/quotequadsco/public_html/pandoc_jats ;echo password | sudo 
-S command"); //added a password for sudo command to run as a root user.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell (as root if requested), it solves the limitations of exec() and shell_exec(). Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('pandoc (/root/.cabal/bin/pandoc)');
//the return will be a string containing the return of the command
echo $return1;
```