# Pass PHP variables to a Bash script and then launch it

Tags: php, bash

So, basically, what I want to do is execute this Bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash

path="./"
filename="Ellly.blend"
file=${path}${filename}
description="Test of the api with a simple model"
token_api="ff00ff"
title="Uber Glasses"
tags="test collada glasses"
private=1
password="Tr0b4dor&3"

curl -k -X POST -F "fileModel=@${file}" -F "filenameModel=${filename}" -F "title=${title}" -F "description=${description}" -F "tags=${tags}" -F "private=${private}" -F "password=${password}" -F "token=${token_api}" https://api.sketchfab.com/v1/models
```

Inside a PHP function. Problem is, I don't really see how I can pass to it some variables and then wait for it to end before resuming the PHP function.

Any help ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Note: I didn't do all the settings, just enough I hope you get the idea.*

#### Option 1: Passing parameters

PHP:

```
$file = escapeshellarg($file);
$filename = escapeshellarg($filename);
// escape the others
$output = exec("./bashscript $file $filename $tags $private $password");
```

Bash:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
file=$2
description="Test of the api with a simple model"
token_api="ff00ff"
title="Uber Glasses"
tags=$3
private=$4
password=$5

...
```

---

#### Option 2: Using environment variables

PHP:

```
putenv("FILENAME=$filename");
putenv("FILE=$file");
putenv("TAGS=$tags");
putenv("PRIVATE=$private");
putenv("PASSWORD=$PASSWORD");

$output = exec('./bash_script');
```

Bash:

```
filename=$FILENAME
file=$FILE
description="Test of the api with a simple model"
token_api="ff00ff"
title="Uber Glasses"
tags=$TAGS
private=$PRIVATE
password=$PASSWORD

...
```

Comment: Ok ok, I get it :) (just a little detail, is there a way to instead of having `./bashscript` to link the Bash file, directly having the script inside `exec();` ? )

Comment: @Axiol Not sure what you mean.  `exec` basically runs something as if you are at the command line.  Just give it the name of the script to run and you'll be fine.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not work.
<?php
putenv("DAYS_BACK=1");
putenv("FILE_TYPE=php");
putenv("DEPLOYMET_KEY=4262022");
$output = exec('bash /portal/deploy/get.sh');
echo $output;
?>